# hash in href link to be sent to controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an action div like below

```
<div class="action">
    <a href="/sertanarig/calismalar/theschoolforgods#" class="grid-item-link"></a>
    <div class="top">
        <a href="#add-to-list-lightbox" class="fa fa-plus add-to-list" data-id="53431d26721730077443eee2" data-type="Work">
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
                <a href="/sertanarig/calismalar/theschoolforgods#">
                        <h4 class="grid-item-name">The School for Gods #1</h4>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="comments">
                        <i class="fa fa fa-comments-o"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

When `/sertanarig/calismalar/theschoolofgods#` clicked, it supposed to send theschoolofgods# to the controller as an argument, but it just sends theschoolofgods, and leaves out the hash symbol and page goes to the top. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The hash is NOT sent to the server. That is how HTTP Requests work.

Comment: Are there not any workaround? Like encoding before sending and decoding in controller? Or I just simply shouldn't keep any record that contains # symbol?

Comment: Should start with what you are trying to do first. Likely a different approach you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hash parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) are for client side only.

If you wish for the hash to be sent server side you should encode it.

```
<a href="/sertanarig/calismalar/theschoolforgods%23">
```

You could use `@Url.Encode` for example.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the current problem but what if the link contains & or any other character? I used Url.Encode but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Url.Encode did the job, I was looking at the wrong page, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the # symbol, as it is used for the [anchor](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) system (a reference for an element present in the **current** page)

I recommend you to encode it, or to use another symbol